# Drupal 7: Custom Theme Failure on New Install (local to remote environment)

Tags: theming

I've created a custom Drupal theme based on the Framework theme on a local Drupal 7 install. It's time to start developing more of the website so I created a fresh Drupal 7 install on a server that will be accessible by my coworkers for review and content creation. The new install went smoothly, the core themes all work, the base Framework theme even works fine, but my custom theme is having major issues.

When setting my theme as default the admin menu disappears, almost none of the actual HTML/PHP of the page loads, and the CSS file doesn't load at all.

I've cleared all the caches, I've given near full permissions on all files/folders in the theme, and nothing has changed a thing.

The Drupal error log spit out the following errors:

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/drupal/sites/cals.arizona.edu.herbarium/themes/dendritic/html.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in theme_render_template() (line 1517 of /var/drupal/includes/theme.inc).

Warning: include(/var/drupal/sites/cals.arizona.edu.herbarium/themes/dendritic/html.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in theme_render_template() (line 1517 of /var/drupal/includes/theme.inc).
```

And the same type of errors for the region and block tpl files.

I'm at a total loss and could use some help, I've been searching endlessly and without any progress.

Thank you.

Comment: And you are absolutely sure `/var/drupal/sites/cals.arizona.edu.herbarium/themes/dendritic/html.tpl.php` exists?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the theme folder on the server. I see it, I know it's there.

http://s11.postimg.org/6fzsh1er7/thethemefilesexist.png

Comment: and all the directory permissions are open as well? I can see `..` (themes) appears to be correct but what about `dendritic` itself?

Comment: The dendritic and themes folders are both set to 775. The framework theme is also in that same folder, and it works fine.

Comment: well, grr.  if you can enable the theme, it means drupal can see other files (like dendritic.info) in that directory, so the only other thing I can think of is some wild character is in there that that you can't see or your GUI isn't showing.

Comment: So, I attacked it again this morning, decided to match permissions to my other working theme (set all to 644), and BOOM everything is loading now except my images. I'm getting this error

    Warning: include(images/whitecircle.svg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 71 of /var/drupal/sites/cals.arizona.edu.herbarium/themes/dendritic/page.tpl.php).